# iPhone Programming -- Table Populated with Type Object

Tags: c#, iphone, xamarin.ios, xamarin, tableview

I am trying to create a table that is filled is textfields and labels, but am having a tricky time populating it.  Errors are being thrown as if the table will only accept strings into its cells.

My code is as follows--I tried to make it as brief as is sensible.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Drawing;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;


namespace Hello_Multiscreen
{
public class TableSource : UITableViewSource {
    object[] tableItems;
    string cellIdentifier = "TableCell";
    public TableSource (object[] items)
    {
        tableItems = items;
    }
    public override int RowsInSection (UITableView tableview, int section)
    {
        return tableItems.Length;
    }
    public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (cellIdentifier);
        // if there are no cells to reuse, create a new one
        if (cell == null)
            cell = new UITableViewCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cellIdentifier);

        return cell;
    }
}
}
```

In my screen class that is using this table, the ViewDidLoad method has

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();
            // adds the table to the view
            table = new UITableView(View.Bounds); // defaults to Plain style

        // load in a string of the values from that database corresponds to all scope--allow user to click on them

UITextField txtFld = new UITextField();

        object[] tableItems = new object[] {txtFld, txtFld, txtFld};
        // select a table source--the table name is the same as the control id name that was dragged
        table.Source = new TableSource(tableItems);
        Add (table);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create a custom UITableViewCell.  The standard TableCell has labels for text, but not arbitrary objects or input fields.

Xamarin provides [MonoTouch.Dialog](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/monotouch.dialog) for building tables, and includes multiple options for different types of input fields.